# Using overloaded operand "+" inside overloaded operand "<<" case error in C++

Tags: c++, overloading, operands

First of all, I tried to find solution on internet. In many tutorials I found how to overload operand, but nowhere I found overloaded operand using inside another overloaded operand.

I have a problem with "<<" and "+", using together

I create structur for complex number, represented by real and imaginary part.
After, I create overloaded operand "+" which adds two of these structures, and operator "<<" which allows to print this structure.

When compiled on Visual Studio everything is fine, but when I try to compile it on linux (command g++ -o -pedantic -Wall a.cpp):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

struct  Complex {
double   re;    
double   im;    
};

Complex  operator + (Complex  Skl1,  Complex  Skl2)
{
Complex  result;
result.re = Skl1.re + Skl2.re;
result.im = Skl1.im + Skl2.im;
return result;
}

ostream & operator << (ostream & stream, Complex & Skl1)
{
stream << "(" << Skl1.re << showpos << Skl1.im << noshowpos << "i" << ")";
return stream;
}

int main(){
Complex L1, L2; 
L1.re = 1;
L1.im = 2;
L2.re = 3;
L2.im = 4;
cout << L1 + L2;
return 0;
}
```

I see this error:

```
a.cpp:31:8: error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}' and 'Complex')
```

cout << L1 + L2;

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where's the code?

Comment: No, C++ doesn't usually prohibit composing two independent features or two independent uses of a feature. It stands to reason that the returned object isn't playing nice. Maybe your `operator<<` overload takes `Complex&`. You need to post a [mcve] for anyone to be sure.

Comment: You might want to overload the  `std::ostream& operator<<` for `Complex&&`

Comment: post a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

the error you posted is only part of the error code presumably, the surrounding lines will contain more detail

Comment: Thanks for link Chris, I've corrected the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your << operator needs to be declared as:

```
ostream & operator << (ostream & stream, const Complex & Skl1)
```

Comment: The reason being that you can't pass a temporary into a function taking a non-const reference